# Correct way to compare different versions of linear regression models in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using boston house dataset and trying to compare `linear regression` vs `lin_reg with scaled X` vs. `Ridge reg with scaled X`

I've usually used cross validation however want to know what problems may occur when using below methods to make comparison between models.

I just run them one after the other,

Here is my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data["data"], columns=load_boston()["feature_names"])
df["target"] = data["target"]

df.rename(columns={"target":"house_price"}, inplace=True)
y = df["house_price"]
X = df.drop(columns=["house_price"])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

model 1: Linear regression

```
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_train = lin_reg.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = lin_reg.predict(X_test)

train_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred_train))
test_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_test))

print(train_rmse)
print(test_rmse)
```

Model 2: Linear regression with scaled X variables

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_train = lin_reg.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = lin_reg.predict(X_test)

train_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred_train))
test_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_test))

print(train_rmse)
print(test_rmse)
```

Model 3: ridge regression

```
ridge_reg = Ridge(alpha=1, solver="cholesky")
ridge_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_train = ridge_reg.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = ridge_reg.predict(X_test)

train_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred_train))
test_rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_test))

print(train_rmse)
print(test_rmse)
```

these code are run in order, they output similar rmse scores. Is this okay to compare different versions of linear regression models?

Comment: Cross validation, under usual circumstances is  a necessary sufficient way to compare n-models.

Comment: could you describe why comparison of models using method in question would be a problem? Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I've fixed them now.

Comment: Using train/test split good for fast experiments, but in the case of we need to compare n-models, it's more reasonable to test model on a multiple train/test sets, for example model might be able to predict the unseen test set, roughly speaking, by chance the number of examples model able to get right was on the test set and others was on the training set.